# A specific request on a real analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request, metric-spaces, continuity

I would like to find a book on real analysis having the following properties (or different books-references for that matter):

1. Treating metric spaces and completeness/compactness/connectedness. Here I need a variety of examples as incomplete spaces, their completion etc. **The main point** is that I would like the treatment interwoven with analysis on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Treating continuity in a metric space (again, with examples) **and** in $\mathbb{R}$. Again, here I would like to have a thorough explanation with some examples.

Something I have in mind is a modern introductory book on analysis, paying a lot attention to topological/metric properties of spaces/sequences/continuous mappings from the start.

Comment: It seems you're describing Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis*.

Comment: To piggy-back onto lhf's comment, it sounds like you're describing quite a few real analysis texts, for instance Charles Pugh's "Real Mathematical Analysis", Richard Goldberg's "Methods of Real Analysis", Lang's book, etc.

Comment: Carothers Real analysis.

Comment: I also recommend [Carothers' book](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521497566) mentioned by @Aram , a book I didn't happen to think of earlier. I think this book might be very good for what you want.